# Publishing web deploy package to azure using Powershell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have the following powershell script to publish the same bits to webapps in different location.

```
Param(
[String]$WebsiteBaseName="mywebsitename",
[String]$WebDeployPackage="./test.zip",
[String]$locations="eastus;westus"
)
Select-AzureRmProfile -Path ./rmprofile

$locationArray = $locations -split ';'
# Iterate and deploy the package
for($i = 1; $i -le $locationArray.Length; $i++) {
    $WebsiteFullName = "'$WebsiteBaseName-$i'"

    Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Package "$WebDeployPackage" -Name $WebsiteFullName
}
```

But when running the script I'm getting the following error.

```
Publish-AzureWebsiteProject : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path2
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using the same code I found in the documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722468.aspx).
The example shows the same code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you hit a bug... if you run Get-Module in that PowerShell session what version is listed for the "Azure" module?

Answer (score 0):

May be remove the double quotes in the script <"$WebDeployPackage">

Comment: Can you add more info on this one.